# Tumblr Custom URL Not Letting Me Save

Tags: url, tumblr, redirect

I have bought a domain that I want to use as a unique Tumblr website but I can't get the url to pick up on Tumblr settings.

The domain is a .com registered with 123-reg. I've set the CNAME to the correct tumblr url and also set the A record too. When I visit the url I get the Tumblr error page so I know that the domain is pointing, however when I go to settings in Tumblr and "Test" the url it says that it's not pointing and I can't save it. What could be the problem?

Comment: You only need to set the `A-record` or `CNAME`, not both: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

Comment: I know - I changed it back to just the CNAME but it's still not working

Comment: Can you share the domain you are wanting to use? After you run `Test Your Domain` did you have an issues?

Comment: Yes that's when I get the issue - A red box pops up saying that CNAME isn't directed even though when I add the url to a browser I get the Tumblr page. The url is www.thefootscene.com